# WooCommerce - Invalid signature - provided signature does not match when passing "after" parameter

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress, woocommerce, oauth

**Solved it:**
Looks like "after" was supposed to be passed in $parameters and in the query too, but not encoded.

```
foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
  $encodedParams[rawurlencode($key)] =
    $key == "after" ? $value : rawurlencode($value);
}
```

After doing above the filter now works.

below is the code I am using to fetch orders from WooCommerce. I did it as described in the documentation and it works perfectly fine.

However, I am trying to get orders which are created only after certain date but when I try to pass in "after" parameter I get 401 Error saying "Invalid signature - provided signature does not match.".

I don't understand how should I pass in the "after" parameter and generate signature so it works.

Also, if there's better way of generating the signature, please let me know!

I appreciate any help provided.

```
$http_method = "GET";
$request_url = "http://myurl.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders";

$parameters = [
  "oauth_consumer_key" => "ck_example",
  "oauth_timestamp" => time(),
  "oauth_nonce" => md5(mt_rand()),
  "oauth_signature_method" => "HMAC-SHA1",
  "oauth_version" => "1.0",
];

$encodedParams = [];
foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
  $encodedParams[rawurlencode($key)] = rawurlencode($value);
}

uksort($encodedParams, "strcmp");

$base =
  strtoupper($http_method) .
  "&" .
  rawurlencode($request_url) .
  "&" .
  rawurlencode(http_build_query($encodedParams));

$key = rawurlencode("cs_example") . "&";

$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $base, $key, true));

$encodedParams["signature"] = $signature;

$header = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"{$encodedParams["oauth_consumer_key"]}\",oauth_signature_method=\"{$encodedParams["oauth_signature_method"]}\",oauth_timestamp=\"{$encodedParams["oauth_timestamp"]}\",oauth_nonce=\"{$encodedParams["oauth_nonce"]}\",oauth_version=\"{$encodedParams["oauth_version"]}\",oauth_signature=\"{$encodedParams["signature"]}\"";

$response = Http::withHeaders([
  "Authorization" => $header,
  "Content-Type" => "application/json"
])->get($request_url);

$response->json();
```

I tried passing it as a parameter in $parameters array and/or passing it as a query parameter in get() but it doesn't seem to do the trick. Also, tried including it in the $request_url and adding it to parameters as well but I still get Invalid Signature 401 Error.

*Update:*

If I do it like below I get Invalid Signature error but if I pass in `["after" => $encodedParams["after"]]` in query I get "Invalid parameter(s): after".

```
$parameters = [
  "oauth_consumer_key" => "",
  "oauth_timestamp" => time(),
  "oauth_nonce" => md5(mt_rand()),
  "oauth_signature_method" => "HMAC-SHA1",
  "oauth_version" => "1.0",
  "after" => "2024-01-10 09:45:17"
];

...

$response = Http::withHeaders([
  "Authorization" => $header,
  "Content-Type" => "application/json"
])->get($request_url, ["after" => $parameters["after"]]);
```

Comment: _"I tried passing it as a parameter in $parameters array and/or passing it as a query parameter in get() but it doesn't seem to do the trick."_ - it _needs_ to be in both places, of course. The signature is supposed to be "for" the request that you are making - so if the signature calculation included a GET parameter you are not even passing with the actual request, then of course it will be off.

Comment: But it doesn't work, even if I pass it in the $parameters array and in the query together I still get "Invalid signature - provided signature does not match."

Comment: Please show what exactly you added and where, directly in the above code.

Comment: Looks okay to me, apart from `"Content-Type" => "application/json"` - you're making a GET request with parameters appended to the URL, so this doesn't have anything to do with JSON.

Comment: I solved it and updated the code again looks like "after" was supposed to be passed in $parameters and in the query too, but not encoded.

Comment: Yes, the `Http` client will apply URL-encoding to the passed parameters on its own. So if you pass an _already_ encoded value, it will get encoded a second time, and that falsifies the data you are actually sending, and therefor the signature won't match any more either.